# "Batch" Write double % to another file

Tags: batch-file

Okay, i need some help with this. I'm trying to make my file write double % into another file.

Code:

```
    echo for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%fnvn%.bat) do ( >>file.bat
    echo   echo %%a >>file.bat
    echo ) >>file.bat
    echo ping localhost -n 4 >nul >>file.bat
    echo exit >>file.bat
```

Output in other file:

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %a in (%fnvn%.bat) do (
       echo %a
    )
    ping localhost -n 4 >nul
    exit
```

But i want to be like this:

```
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%fnvn%.bat) do (
       echo %%a
    )
    ping localhost -n 4 >nul
    exit
```

Comment: `echo echo %%a` is still going to try and expand that variable. you'd need `echo echo %%%%a` or whatever

Comment: haha! Thanks! I tried using 3 % but i didn't think of 4.. Haha! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) already wrote, `echo echo %%%%a` is required here.

Each percent sign which should be written into the file must be escaped with one more percent sign.